# How to recover RSA messages if they are padded with spaces?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, padding, ctf

I have a message `m="hunter"`. Let's say we pad it with 2 spaces from the left making the final message as `m_dash="  hunter"`.

We are given with c where `c=pow(bytes_to_long(m_dash), 3, n)` and `n(1024 bit)`.
n is too big to be factorised and therefore we can't get the totient and thus 'd'. And because of that we can't recover our padded-message by `pow(c,d,n)`.
Is there any way I can get my message back?

Comment: Can you maybe clarify a little bit.
I don't see how padding with spaces are making a difference here.
c will be different between padding and not padding obviously, but wouldn't the ablitity to recover m, be the same regardless.

Comment: Also unless I am misunderstanding your question, it might be better at home at https://crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why can't you remove the 4 spaces after you decrypt?

Comment: Because we dont have 'd'. Thus, we can't do pow(c,d,n).

Comment: If you can get hold of the ciphertext for the encryption of the same message with 3 different moduli then you can recover the plaintext. If the message space is very small then you can brute-force try all possible messages and see which one encrypts to your ciphertext.

Comment: If your plaintext is less than 42 characters, then it will only contain 336 bits at most. If you encrypt that with e=3 and a 1024-bit modulus, the result will be 1008 bits at most. That means you can decrypt it simply by calculating the cube root.